# How to zoom in and zoom out on stage with actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, zooming

I need to zoom in and zoom out stage for android with ActionScript 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scaleX and scaleY properties on your container to simulate zoom. Increase the scale to zoom in and decrease it to zoom out.